# Splitting String into object fields

Tags: java

I looking for best aproach for this problem. 
String example:

```
{"id":16,"title":"title1","description":"Quote \"foo\" asdf","execution_time":"2017-04-26 06:15:00"}
```

I need to create new object with gets fields values from the string. What is correct way to do it? Creating constructor and pass this string as parameter and use stringtokenizer inside it? Or maybe using Pattern would be better?

Comment: This is JSON. You use a JSON parser to parse JSON. Learn what JSON is, the google for "Parsing JSON in Java".

Comment: @JBNizet i know this is JSON but i need to pass values to the custom class. Or it will be easier to conver this string to json object and pass json as parameter?

Comment: *I need to create new object with gets fields values from the string*: that's what a JSON parser is all about. You want to extract information from this JSON string, so parse it using a JSON parser, which will return a custom object (if the parser binds to classes), or a Map, or a JSONObject.

Comment: True. For instance, `Gson` is a library able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

(I am going to correct the code)
I am proposing to use org.json.simple.*. In my opinion, it will be easy, for example:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONValue;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class ParseJson1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "....";
        /*
         * {"id":16,"title":"title1","description":"Quote \"foo\" asdf","execution_time":"2017-04-26 06:15:00"}
         */
        try {
            String genreJson = IOUtils.toString(new URL(url));
            JSONObject genreJsonObject = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parseWithException(genreJson);
            // get the title
            System.out.println(genreJsonObject.get("title"));
            // get the data
            JSONArray genreArray = (JSONArray) genreJsonObject.get("dataset");
            // get the first genre
            JSONObject firstGenre = (JSONObject) genreArray.get(0);
            System.out.println(firstGenre.get("genre_title"));
        } catch (IOException | ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```